Cannot run react native project on iPad simulator
I am on a Mac M1 and I am trying to run an existing react native project on my iPad simulator. When I run react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPad (10th generation)' I get the following logs:
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace app.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme app -destination id=7910F3F2-E156-426B-8FEB-83D55DF8053D

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

2024-05-15 15:46:55.285 xcodebuild[35655:616293] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/3q/n1p_2fp125v74dyn4snmjc2w0000gp/T/ResultBundle_2024-15-05_15-46-0055.xcresult
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { id:7910F3F2-E156-426B-8FEB-83D55DF8053D }




node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace App.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme App -destination id=4B3D7B42-9C2E-4AE1-971F-15030CE1A0E3

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Prepare packages

ComputeTargetDependencyGraph
note: Building targets in dependency order
note: Target dependency graph (1 target)
    Target 'App' in project 'App' (no dependencies)

GatherProvisioningInputs

CreateBuildDescription

ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --version --output-format xml1

ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -v -E -dM -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.4.sdk -x c -c /dev/null

ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -v -E -dM -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.4.sdk -x c -c /dev/null

ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -v -E -dM -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.4.sdk -x objective-c++ -c /dev/null

ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -v -E -dM -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.4.sdk -x objective-c -c /dev/null

ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --print-asset-tag-combinations --output-format xml1 /Users/user/code/xxx/typescript/kiosk-react-native/ios/App/Images.xcassets

ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --version --output-format xml1

ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld -version_details

Build description signature: fbba53c3f5dc8e0b970b93a067c01b26
Build description path: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-anupfnsunjjksofsoenhdffsphkf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/fbba53c3f5dc8e0b970b93a067c01b26.xcbuilddata
/Users/user/code/xxx/typescript/kiosk-react-native/ios/App.xcodeproj:1:1: error: Unable to open base configuration reference file '/Users/user/code/xxx/typescript/kiosk-react-native/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App.debug.xcconfig'. (in target 'App' from project 'App')
warning: Unable to read contents of XCFileList '/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'App' from project 'App')
warning: Unable to read contents of XCFileList '/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-resources-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'App' from project 'App')
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-resources-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'App' from project 'App')
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-resources-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'App' from project 'App')
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'App' from project 'App')
warning: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'App' from project 'App')
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'App' from project 'App')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP] Copy Pods Resources' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'App' from project 'app')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'app' from project 'app')

--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:4B3D7B42-9C2E-4AE1-971F-15030CE1A0E3, OS:17.4, name:iPad (10th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:4B3D7B42-9C2E-4AE1-971F-15030CE1A0E3, OS:17.4, name:iPad (10th generation) }
** BUILD FAILED **

]


The simulator definitely does exist.
I have also opened the app.xcworkspace file in Xcode and set the Targeted Device Families to iPad.
How can I get this app running on my iPad simulator?
Note: I have been able to run other react native applications on my iPad simulator that have worked fine.
